# JSF Primefaces: Bug al exportar rows seleccionadas (excel, pdf)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jtable

Dispongo de una tabla sobre la cual puedo seleccionar varias filas mediante un `checkbox` que seria la columna `selector`:

```
<p:dataTable    value="#{cityBean.cities}" var="city" id="dt_cities" widgetVar="w_cities"
                filteredValue="#{cityBean.filteredCities}"
                selection="#{cityBean.selectedCities}" 
                rowKey="#{city.id}"
                rowSelectMode="add"
                scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300">
    <p:column id="selector" selectionMode="multiple" style="text-align:center" />
    <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{city.name}" filterBy="#{city.name}"  filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{city.name}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Luego tengo dos botones con los que puedo exportar las filas seleccionadas (mediante el `selectionOnly="true"`) de dos formas: `XLS` o `PDF`.

```
<h:commandLink >
   <p:graphicImage url="#{resource['icons/excel_exports.png']}" />
   <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="dt_cities" fileName="list_cities" selectionOnly="true" />
</h:commandLink>
<h:commandLink>
   <p:graphicImage url="#{resource['icons/pdf_exports.png']}" />
   <p:dataExporter type="pdf" preProcessor="#{cityBean.pdfLandscape}" 
                            target="dt_cities" fileName="list_cities" 
                            selectionOnly="true"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

El `bug` con el que me encuentro es que por ejemplo: dispongo de una lista de `10 elementos` numerados del `1 al 10`, selecciono los elementos `9, 8, 5 y 2`. Al pulsar en los botones de exportación me aparecen `4 elementos` pero no corresponden a su selección, aparecen los elementos `1, 2, 3 y 4`.

Reconoce cuantos elementos están seleccionados pero no sabe interpretar cuales son.

Actualmente estoy utilizando: `JSF 2.2` y `Primefaces 5.1 RC1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probablemente sea un error propio de *Primefaces 5.1.*

Para el caso de la exportación a *PDF*:

Te propongo que agregues a tu proyecto, *primefaces-extensions 3.0.0*, que es la versión compatible con *Primefaces 5.1*. Si usas *Maven* esto sería así:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

En tu *XHTML* agrega el espacio de nombres siguiente:

```
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
```

... y en tu botón, en lugar de usar `p:dataExporter`, utiliza `pe:exporter`.

```
<h:commandLink>
   <p:graphicImage url="#{resource['icons/pdf_exports.png']}" />
   <pe:exporter type="pdf" preProcessor="#{cityBean.pdfLandscape}" 
                            target="dt_cities" fileName="list_cities" 
                            selectionOnly="true"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

La etiqueta `pe:exporter` te permite también exportar a *Excel*, pero solo lo hace hacia a *XLSX* y no a *XLS*.

Comment: Lamentablemente no se usa maven en este proyecto, pero lo tengo en cuenta, muchas gracias por tu alternativa :)

Answer (score 0):

Añade una columna y comprueba que el campo `id` de cada `city` sea único. Por ejemplo:

```
<p:column id="cityId" value="#{city.id}" />
```

Comment: No es ninguna solución a mi problema, es un caso de prueba básico que ya probé en su momento.